# How to loop through all items in xpath

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

I'm new to both xpath and html so I'm probably missing something fundamental here. I have a html where I want to extract all the items displayed below. (I'm using scrapy to do my requests, I just need the proper xpath to get the data)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5GzR.png)

Here I just want to loop through all these items and from there and get some data from inside each item.

```
for item in response.xpath("//ul[@class='feedArticleList XSText']/li[@class='item']"):
   yield {'name': item.xpath("//div[@class='intro lhNormal']").get()}
```

The problem is that this get only gives me the first item for all the loops. If I instead use .getall() I then get all the items for every loop (which in my view shouldn't work since I thought I only selected one item at the time in each iteration). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your sample HTML as text not as an image for further assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're missing a `.` in your XPath expression (to "indicate" you're working from a context node).

Replace :

```
yield {'name': item.xpath("//div[@class='intro lhNormal']").get()}
```

For :

```
yield {'name': item.xpath(".//div[@class='intro lhNormal']").get()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do miss smth. fundamental. Python by default does not have `xpath()` function.
You better use bs4 or [lxml](https://lxml.de/) libraries.
See an example with lxml:

```
import lxml.html
import os 
doc = lxml.html.parse('http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org')
if doc:
    table = []
    trs = doc.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr")
    for tr in islice(trs, 3):
         for td in tr.xpath('td'):
             table += td.xpath("/b/text() | /text()")
    buffer = ''
    for i in range(len(table)):
        buffer += table[i]
```

the full explanation is [here](https://webscraping.pro/python-lxml-scrape-online-dictionary/).

Comment: No I'm using scrapy and I already have my response. The problem was just getting the right xpath expression to extract the data.

Comment: @Jh123, if "I'm using scrapy and I already have my response", then you better display it in your question code.